# AWS Beanstalk New Node Platform 'None' for Reverse Proxy Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, reverse-proxy

AWS Beanstalk just deprecated a Node 12 platform and introduced a new minor version.

The old version had options for either

1. Apache
2. NGINX
3. None

With this new minor update, the 'None' option is now removed from the dropdown.

Is there any way to opt out of using a reverse-proxy for new Node environments now? (I would think through deliberately specifying through .ebextensions, but I'd rather not do that seeing as it used to be an option). Thanks!

Comment: I added an option in an .ebextensions config file to set the Proxy Server to None. But I get an error while deploying, "Invalid option value: 'none' (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy', OptionName: 'ProxyServer'): Value is not one of the allowed values: [apache, nginx]
". So, looks like it may not be allowed.

Maybe the only option is to shell into the ec2 instance and manually disable NGINX

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-nodejs